# New to coding and trying to plus two divs together where one div is plus 6 and the other is 1

Tags: javascript, html

`https://codepen.io/nicklock804/pen/WNemWGz`

so what i am trying to do is a sum of

resultA + pointA = totalScoreA (where resultA = 6 and pointA =1)

this is same for team B divs

I tried this but it did not work

```
function totalScoreA() {
   totalA = 6;
   totalScoreA = totalA + totalPA;
   document.getElementById( "totalScoreA" ).innerHTML = totalA + totalPA;
}
```

If any could help that would be amazing.

Thanks Guys

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)  :)

Answer (score 0):

In function totalScoreA() you have this calculation totalScoreA = totalA + totalPA; and the variable name is same name as the function name. You can't do this because once you do that calculation the function name is no longer available.

I've made some other minor changes where the calculation is updated immediately. This is done by calling totalScoreA(); whenever GoalA(), subGoalA(), pointA() and subPointA() is called.

You also had two pointA() functions, I've deleted one of these.

You have to apply changes I made in A to B

```
    //A team

        var totalA = 0;

document.getElementById('resetA').onclick = resetA;
document.getElementById('GoalA').onclick = GoalA;
document.getElementById('subGoalA').onclick = subGoalA;

function resetA() {
  totalA = 0;
  totalPA = 0;
  document.getElementById('resultA').innerHTML = totalA;
  document.getElementById('pointA').innerHTML = totalPA;
  totalScoreA();
}



function GoalA() {
  totalA = totalA + 1;
  document.getElementById('resultA').innerHTML = totalA;
  totalScoreA();
}

function subGoalA() {
  totalA = totalA - 1;
  document.getElementById('resultA').innerHTML = totalA;
  totalScoreA();
}


    var totalPA = 0;

    document.getElementById('PointA').onclick = PointA;
    document.getElementById('subPointA').onclick = subPointA;


    function PointA() {
  totalPA = totalPA + 1;
  document.getElementById('pointA').innerHTML = totalPA;
    totalScoreA();
}


    function subPointA() {
  totalPA = totalPA - 1;
  document.getElementById('pointA').innerHTML = totalPA;
    totalScoreA();
}

    function totalScoreA() {
        //totalA = 6;
        //totalScoreA = totalA + totalPA;
        document.getElementById( "totalScoreA" ).innerHTML = totalA + totalPA;

    }
// B team


    var total = 0;

document.getElementById('resetB').onclick = resetB;
document.getElementById('GoalB').onclick = GoalB;
document.getElementById('SubGoalB').onclick = SubGoalB;


function resetB() {
  total = 0;
  totalPB = 0;
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = total;
  document.getElementById('Points').innerHTML = totalPB;
}

function GoalB() {
  total = total + 1;
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = total;
}

function SubGoalB() {
  total = total - 1;
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = total;
}


    var totalPB = 0

    document.getElementById('PointB').onclick = PointB;
    document.getElementById('subPointB').onclick = subPointB;

    function PointB() {
  totalPB = totalPB + 1;
  document.getElementById('Points').innerHTML = totalPB;
}
    function subPointB() {
  totalPB = totalPB - 1;
  document.getElementById('Points').innerHTML = totalPB;
}
```